# Functions used for switching between colors of drawing

Tags: javascript, html, function, drawing, interactive

I'm working on a color switching drawing.
The switch is two buttons the first is changing the colours the other one draws the new picture.
I found this problem: After I switched on and off once the buttons don't do anyhing visible.
Any suggestions how to solve it? (I'm a beginner--> I apperciate simple solutions)

```
<script>
var d = document.getElementById("1")
var dtx = d.getContext('2d');
var C;
var L;

function Func()
{
if (isFinite(L))
    {   C = ["#33FFFF","#993300"];
        L="A";
    }
else
        C = ["#33CCCC","#663300"];
        L="1";
}
function Draw()
{
    dtx.clearRect(0, 0,d.width, d.height);
    dtx.fillStyle= C[0];
    dtx.fillRect(20,20,20,20);
    dtx.beginPath();
    dtx.fillStyle= C[1];
    dtx.fillRect(60,60,20,20);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Add please HTML.

Comment: "the buttons don't do anyhing visible" can you be more specific please?

Comment: I mean pushing again the light button(runs "Func()") should switch the colors back to darker colors but the colors keep being bright